# What is the difference between these 2 ANDing circuits?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, diodes, logic-gates

[image]

- What is the difference between ANDing using series resistors and ANDing using diodes?
- Is it dependent on the nature of signals X1 and X2( open drain, active low or pushpull)?

Comment: Why do you think that the 3-resistor circuit on the left is an AND logic gate? IMO it is just a passive voltage summer. And what is the point of "ANDing using series resistors"? Where are these series resistors here?

Comment: @Circuitfantasist, both are "and" circuits.  The first circuit does not work with active high signals.

Comment: @skvery, maybe you mean that X1 and X2 are produced by open collectors (drains)? But then what is the function of R1 and R2? The open colectors can be directly connected to the output node in a 'wired OR'...

Answer (score 1):

The diode AND provides excellent pulldown, and provides slow pullup but a strong "High" level that is limited only by leakage currents in downstream diodes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your circuit, but there could be a lot of differences.

First: With diodes you will not be able to pull the output below the diodes forward voltage, which could be 0.7V. With a resistor divider, you could go lower in voltage.

Second: The diodes can handle a push-pull configuration for X1/X2 because if one signal line is driving VCC, the other still can pull the output down.

Third: The diodes do not protect the outputs against overvoltage, but are a good protection against voltage below zero from the output terminal.

Fourth: The diodes capacitance may make the signal slower to rise, so the max. communication speed is reduced.

... and so on...

Answer (score 0):

### Resistor implementation:

- AND-ing works only if X1 and X2 are open drain signals, which would have only 2 states - Floating, GND(=low).

[image]

- If X1 goes low it will make X2 also low by default( R2 acts an unitentional pulldown). This will cause a problem if X2 is independently being used in many places and they would expecting a floating X2.

### Diode implementation:

- X1 and X2 can be either be open drain or push-pull.
- If any one of the input goes low, o/p cannot go high. Remember if the cathode is at 0V, anode cannot go higher than 0.7V ever.
- If X1 goes low it will make output low but X2 can still remain floating/high
- Hence when we use the same signal in multiple places use diode implementation

Comment: OK, I agree with your explanations. R1 and R2 act as decoupling elements (really, quite imperfect). Decoupling diodes are quite more perfect. BTW R1 and R2 (and R3) really constitute a resistor summing network. If it drives a threshold element, this circuit can act both as OR and AND logic gate depending on the value of the threshold. RTL logic gates are based on this idea. It is interesting that an analog resistor network is used to implement a digital circuit (logic gate)... an arithmetic operation is used to implement a logic operation.